# To show a subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ isn't a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $S$ = {$a(\frac{2}{3})^k$: $k\in \Bbb{N}$, $a \in \Bbb{Z}$}

I am trying to prove that $S$ is not a subring.

I am trying to do the following:

Let $a = 1$ and $k = 1$.

Then $\frac{2}{3} \in S$.

If $S$ is a subring then $\frac{2}{3}+(\frac{2}{3})^2$ which reduces to $\frac{10}{9}$ must belong to $S$.

Now how can I show that it doesn't?

How to show that there does not exist a natural number $k$ and natural number $a$ such that $a(\frac{2}{3})^k$ = $\frac{10}{9}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac{10}{9}$ would belong to $S$, it would exist $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$a\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = \frac{10}{9}$$ or

$$a  2^{k-1} = 5 \cdot 3^{k-2}.$$

As $5$ is a prime number, $5 | a$ and it exists $b \in \mathbb Z$ with
$$b 2^{k-1} = 3^{k-2}.$$

$k > 2$ is not possible as this would imply that $ 2 | 3$.

Therefore $k=1,2$ are the only options. $k=2$ leads to the contradiction $2b=1$. And $k=1$ to the other contradiction that the integer $b$ is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Why can't 5 divide 2^(k-1)?..and If k>2 then how does it imply 2|3?

Comment: $2^{k-1}$ is a power of $2$. Hence its only prime divider is $2$. $b\cdot 2 \cdot 2{k-2}=3^{k-2}$ implies that $2$ divides $3^{k-2}$ and hence $3$ according to Gauss theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = \frac{10}{9}$ for $k>1$ then we have

$$9a\cdot 2^k = 10\cdot 3^k \Rightarrow a\cdot2^{k-1} = 5\cdot 3^{k-2}$$

but then the LHS is even, while the RHS is odd, which is a contradiction. When $k = 1$ then $18a = 30$, which clearly has no solutions for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore there are no numbers $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = \frac{10}{9}$.